# Save/persist jupyter notebooks created in docker container on Windows 10 host

Tags: windows, docker, jupyter-notebook

I am trying my hands on docker and I have spun up a container jupyter/minimal-notebook with the command.

`docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter/minimal-notebook`

I have created notebooks to test it out but they don't seem to be saved in host OS(**Windows 10**).

How can i share jupyter notebooks between Host OS and container.

Comment: Use [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). Find the location where notebook data is saved in the container and bind it to a host directory. Read more [here](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)(especially Example 3).

Answer (score 1):

you can share using volume mount from Host OS to Guest OS.

something like :

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v /your-jupyter/work:home/jovyan/work jupyter/scipy-notebook
```

read more about volume : https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/